# How do I iterate the contents of an LLVM DynamicLibrary?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, llvm

I have loaded a `.dylib` using LLVM:

```
auto library = llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::getPermanentLibrary(libraryPath.c_str());
```

I would like to list the mangled names in the library, along with their locations in memory.

`DynamicLibrary` provides helpful methods for getting the address of a given name, but I would like to list all of the names. I assume that somewhere inside LLVM is a map of names to memory addresses.

How do I iterate through this map?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such map. llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary() is just a thin wrapper over libdl (dlsym()) / Win32 API (GetProcAddress()) plus some additional vector for addresses of explicitly registered / special symbols.